# Excel - Find relevant column by matching cell value across multiple columns to compile AVERAGEIFS function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two datasets:

1. List of locations and a start date and end date for each location

| Location Name | Start Date | End Date | Average Temp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Location 1 | 01/01/2019 | 01/02/2019 |  |
| Location 2 | 01/02/2020 | 01/03/2020 |  |

2. Column A contains every day from 01/01/2018 to 31/12/2021 and each column corresponds to one of the locations where the temperature is captured for that date at that location

| Date | Location 1 | Location 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2018 | 21 | 15 |
| 02/01/2018 | 23 | 16 |

What I need is a formula to provide the average temperature for that location between the two dates. Assuming I know the correct column, the formula is easy:

`AVERAGEIFS(COLUMN B, DATE,>= START DATE, DATE, <= END DATE)`

What I'm struggling with is how do I identify the correct column using the location names? I know I can use `MATCH` to find the column number and I don't know how to translate that to the column letter in a way that makes sense for the formula.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the column letter, what you can do is combine `MATCH` with `INDEX` to return the correct data for the specified location.

If the first data set was in F1:I3 you could use this formula in I2 and copy it down.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(INDEX($B$2:$C$1501, ,MATCH(F2, $B$1:$C$1)),$A$2:$A$1501, ">="&G2, $A$2:$A$1501, "<=" &H2)
```

[image]

Comment: That works, thank you! I don't fully understand how but happy to run with it for now and work it out later. Many thanks.